# asp net core mysql connection with entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

I want to add entity framework to my API project, my database is mysql

how can I do it

.net core version:2.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore).

> 1) Install the MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore NuGet package.
>
> 2) In the class that derives from the DbContext class, override the OnConfiguring method to set the MySQL data provider with UseMySQL. The following example shows how to set the provider using a generic connection string in C#.

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{   
    optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;database=library;user=user;password=password");
}
```

Check the available MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html) for more details.

Comment: This has been removed. You can use MySql.EntityFrameworkCore instead.